# Captcha in my Joomla site it not blocking spam robots

Tags: joomla

In my joomla install I have removed the email registration and instead added a Captcha field to the PHP code using the recaptcha.net method.

For some reason I am still getting what I think are spam users (robots) but I don't know how they would get around the Captcha field.

Anything I should check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this using http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/authentication/7727